# Errors on importing Oracle backup

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, import, oracle12c

I have created a directory:

`SQL> create or replace directory dir as '/home/oracle12c/Desktop/latest_exp.dmp';`

I am trying to run an import, as sysdba:

```
impdp \'/as sysdba\' full=Y directory=dir dumpfile=importDump.dmp logfile=import.log;
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics, and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

As far as I can see from the result on my search, it as to do with permissions. The Oracle user should own the files.
The permission to the file I am trying to import looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle12c root 2201247744 Feb 21 16:51 latest_exp.dmp
```

What is my problem here, and how do I overcome it? Is there a problem when the owner of the file is oracle12? Some solutions on the internet say that the files must be owned by the user trying to access the files, who in my case is sysdba. But I cannot change the owner to my file to be sysdba, as that user does not exist on my Ubuntu.

Also, we specify the dumfile and logfile, but we do not specify the location. Where will it create the locations for these? I assumed it would look for them here: `/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl$` where orcl is my SID

I have not been able to solve my problem with the help of Google and Oracle Doc.

I am running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle directory object should point to an operating system directory, not a file; instead of:

```
create or replace directory dir as '/home/oracle12c/Desktop/latest_exp.dmp'
```

it should just be:

```
create or replace directory dir as '/home/oracle12c/Desktop'
```

The dump file should sit in that directory, and by default the log and bad files will be created in there too.

At the moment you're asking it to create log file under the directory `/home/oracle12c/Desktop/latest_exp.dmp`, i.e. `/home/oracle12c/Desktop/latest_exp.dmp/import.log` - which clearly isn't a valid full path; and also to look for the file `importDump.dmp` under that not-a-directory.

Your command line looks like it has the wrong name anyway:

```
impdp ... directory=dir dumpfile=latest_exp.dmp logfile=import.log
```